# Using Linq to objects, ToDictionary method not satisfying type requirement

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, casting

I need to pass a variable of type `IDictionary<Guid, IEnumerable<Guid>>` into a method.  When I use the following code:

```
var userGroupDictionary = _selectedUsers.ToDictionary(u => u.UserGuid, u => u.GroupUsers.Select(gu => gu.Group.GroupGuid).ToList());
```

I get the following error:

```
cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.Guid,System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Guid>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<System.Guid,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Guid>>'
```

When I iterate through my collection it works however:

```
var userGroupDictionary = new Dictionary<Guid, IEnumerable<Guid>>();
foreach (var user in _selectedUsers.Where(user => !userGroupDictionary.ContainsKey(user.UserGuid)))
{
    userGroupDictionary.Add(user.UserGuid, user.GroupUsers.Select(gu => gu.Group.GroupGuid).ToList());
}
```

Any ideas what's going on?  Is the compiler unable to tell that `Dictionary<Guid, List<Guid>>` satisfies `IDictionary<Guid, IEnumerable<Guid>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that type inference is returning a `Dictionary<Guid, List<Guid>>`, which is the wrong type for the method you want to call. There's a bit more to it than that, but it involves a type variance discussion. You can solve the problem with the [AsEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx) extension:

```
var userGroupDictionary = _selectedUsers
    .ToDictionary(
        u => u.UserGuid,
        u => u.GroupUsers.Select(gu => gu.Group.GroupGuid).ToList().AsEnumerable());
```

...or you can do a simple cast, as in the following:

```
var userGroupDictionary = _selectedUsers
    .ToDictionary(
        u => u.UserGuid,
        u => (IEnumerable<Guid>)u.GroupUsers.Select(gu => gu.Group.GroupGuid).ToList());
```

If you merely omit the `ToList()` as others have recommended, the type inference will indeed render the type you expect, but the `IEnumerable` returned will have deferred-execution which may or may not be an issue for you. Leaving `ToList` in there but doing a cast of sorts will immediately evaluate the items instead of lazily evaluating them at the time of iteration.

For more detail on deferred execution, see the "laziness" (think lazy-evaluation) section of [Jon Skeet's Edulinq series, part 44](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/02/21/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-44-aspects-of-design.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I was running into problems with the deferred execution. I wouldn't have thought of the AsEnumerable after the evaluation.  I would like to know more about the type variance issue though and will likely post another question.  Your answer works great for me though, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Line below creates a dictionary where a key of type `Guid` and a value of type `List<Guid>`.

```
_selectedUsers.ToDictionary(
                   u => u.UserGuid, 
                   u => u.GroupUsers.Select(gu => gu.Group.GroupGuid).ToList()
                   );
```

So just remove `.ToList()` and that's it, `u.GroupUsers.Select()` itself returns `IEnumerable<Guid>`.

And you able iterating on both Values since `List` implementes `IEnumerable` as well, this is enought to satisfy `foreach` iterator.

Comment: The `.ToList()` has the effect of enumerating the `u.GroupUsers` right away, which may or may not matter. It will matter if `u.GroupUsers`, for example, gets the results from a database.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the compiler unable to tell that `Dictionary<Guid, List<Guid>>` satisfies `IDictionary<Guid, IEnumerable<Guid>>`

No, the compiler is able to tell that `Dictionary<Guid, List<Guid>>` *doesn't* satisfy `IDictionary<Guid, IEnumerable<Guid>>`. The latter provides, for example, a method `Add(Guid, IEnumerable<Guid>)`, which your dictionary cannot support.

You can explicitly state the allowed values in your dictionary, for example using

```
_selectedUsers.ToDictionary<User, Guid, IEnumerable<Guid>>(
    u => u.UserGuid,
    u => u.GroupUsers.Select(gu => gu.Group.GroupGuid).ToList())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all of u.GroupUsers have Same groupID. You can get first groupID,
If you can Access groupID property on user class. You should use GroupID.
Like `_selectedUsers.ToDictionary(u=>u.UserGuid,u.GroupID);`
If you cant Access to GroupId on user class.
Use :

```
_selectedUsers.ToDictionary(
                   u => u.UserGuid, 
                   u => u.GroupUsers.Select(gu => gu.Group.GroupGuid).First());
```

Comment: Why would they have the same GroupID? The question suggests to me that a user can be a member of multiple groups.

Comment: Scenario. I thought. There are an association User to Group on GroupID.